# How to Call method using its name?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object with some methods and I want to call a method using the method name as string only.

```
object obj;
obj.method();
```

Comment: Know i know what you want to do. But your question is really confusing... Try to edit your question please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given a method MethodName with the signature `void MethodName(int num)`, it would be done something like:

```
   MethodInfo method = obj.GetType().GetMethod("MethodName", 
         BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance)
   method.Invoke(obj, 4) // void method
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to call non-void ones, which return something?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to reflection you may also want to look at [dynamic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2008/10/27/c-dynamic.aspx) invocation; which is latebound (i.e. at runtime as opposed to compile time) dispatch of method invocations.

Answer (score 0):

```
object obj;
var dyn = (dynamic) obj;
dyn.method();
```

Comment: Yes, but the symbol `method` must still appear as a literal in the code.