# Call a method dynamically based on some other variable

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Call method using its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356367/how-to-call-method-using-its-name)

Getting sick of using switch/case statements.  I'm wondering if there is some way to call a method based on the value provided by the user.  Understand that there could be a million reasons why this is a bad idea, but here's what I'm thinking:

```
Console.Write("What method do you want to call? ");
string method_name = Console.ReadLine();
```

then somehow call the method contained in 'method_name'.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 9):

You can use reflection:

```
var type = typeof(MyClass);
var method = type.GetMethod(method_name);
method.Invoke(obj, params);
```

If you want the type to be dynamic as well as the method then use this instead of `typeof(MyClass)`:

```
var type = Type.GetType(type_name);
```

Answer (score 6):

Many times you can refactor switch statements to dictionaries...

```
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case 1: 
        Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
        break;
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine("Case 3");
        break;
}
```

can become ...

```
var replaceSwitch = new Dictionary<int, Action>
    {
        { 1, () => Console.WriteLine("Case 1") }
        { 2, () => Console.WriteLine("Case 2") }
        { 3, () => Console.WriteLine("Case 3") }
    }

...

replaceSwitch[value]();
```

This is a very subtle shift that doesn't seem to gain much, but in reality it's much, much better. If you want to know *why*, this [blog post](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/08/17/pulling-out-the-switch-its-time-for-a-whooping/) explains it very well.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reflection, if you have to act on the user's input value w/o using switch statement, you could use a dictionary having the list of methods mapped against the input value.

```
    private static void Method1(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    private static void Method2(int x)
    {
    }

    private static void Method3(int x)
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Action<int>> methods = new Dictionary<int, Action<int>>();
        methods.Add(1, Method1);
        methods.Add(2,  Method2);
        methods.Add(3, Method3);


        (methods[1])(1);
    }
```

Comment: What if the method type is string, and it has multiple parameter.. for example, string emilvalid(string x1, string x2) and string regExp(string erro).. both are returning string.. can u tell me how to do that ... and what to use insted of action.. #Action is only for void methods.. and FUNC is for returning method .. but it is still giving error..

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting way I have seen to handle(read avoid) switch statements differently is to use a dictionary of methods. I stole this from http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/05/30/c-using-a-dictionary-instead-of-if-statements/ and it looks like they are using the MVC framework but the same basic principal applies

```
public class SomeController
{
private Dictionary<string, Func<UserData,ActionResult>> handleAction = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<UserData,ActionResult>>
    { { "Back", SaveAction },
      { "Next", NextAction },
      { "Save", SaveAction } };

public ActionResult TheAction(string whichButton, UserData userData)
{
    if(handleAction.ContainsKey(whichButton))
    {
        return handleAction[whichButton](userData);
    }

    throw Exception("");
}

private ActionResult NextAction(UserData userData)
{
    // do cool stuff
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sample

```
public class Boss
{
    public void Kick()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Kick");
    }
    public void Talk(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Talk " + message);
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Run");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void AutoSwitch(object obj, string methodName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var objType = typeof(obj);
        var method = objType.GetMethod(methodName);
        method.Invoke(obj, parameters);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new Boss();

        AutoSwitch(obj, "Talk", "Hello World");
        AutoSwitch(obj, "Kick");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking you could somehow do this:

```
Console.Write("What method do you want to call? ");
string method_name = Console.ReadLine();
method_name();
```

You are mistaken. You have to analyze the user input and call a method based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is your friend. Have a look at [`Type.GetMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx).